# What's the Pythonic way to add a parameter to many of the function calls in my code?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Python (3.6) web server using aiohttp with a lot of routes in it.  The handler in my routes usually looks like this:

```
async def __call__(self, request):
    response1 = await call_service_1('aaa')
    response2 = await call_service_2('bbb')
    response3 = await call_service_3('ccc')
    return [response1, response2, response3]
```

And a service call looks like:

```
async def call_service1(self, arg):
    url = 'http://localhost/' + arg
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    async with self.client_session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
        return response
```

I have a new requirement in which I need to read a header value in the request, and pass that on as a header in my subsequent service requests.  I have this requirement for all of my routes and all of my service calls.  My initial attempt to fulfil this requirement would be to change the routes to this:

```
async def __call__(self, request):
    my_header_value = request.headers['my_header_value']  # new header value
    response1 = call_service_1('aaa', my_header_value)
    response2 = call_service_2('bbb', my_header_value)
    response3 = call_service_3('ccc', my_header_value)
```

And to change the service request to this:

```
async def call_service1(self, arg, my_header_value):  # new parameter
    url = 'http://localhost/' + arg
    headers = {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'my_header_value': my_header_value  # new header value
    }
    async with self.client_session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
        return response
```

I don't think this is the Pythonic way to make a change like this.  I think it's a bad design to pass this parameter around like this, from endpoint to endpoint.  I know that this is a cross-cutting concern, but I don't know the proper way to design something to handle this in Python.  I'd ultimately be copying and pasting code all over the place.  There's got to be a better way, but I don't know it and my Python isn't that strong.

For instance, is there some way I can decorate the service calls so that I don't have to add a new parameter all over the place?  I don't think I have access to some session variables that I can set so that I don't have to add parameters at all.  If I did however, I'd be worried about unit testing.

What do you recommend?